# Nested fully qualified property name using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have the following classes:

```
public class Car
{
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }    
    public int Year { get; set; }        
}

public class Engine 
{
    public int HorsePower { get; set; }
    public int Torque { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm getting all the nested properties using this:

```
var result = typeof(Car).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).SelectMany(GetProperties).ToList();

        private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProperties(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass)
            {
                return propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetProperties().SelectMany(prop => GetProperties(prop)).ToList();
            }

            return new [] { propertyInfo };
        }
```

This gives me all the properties of the class. However, when I try and get a nested property from an object, I get an exception:

```
horsePowerProperty.GetValue(myCar); // object doesn't match target type exception
```

This happens because it can't find the property `HorsePower` on the `Car` object. I have looked at all of the properties on `PropertyInfo` and can't seem to find anywhere that has the fully qualified property name. I would then use this to split strings, and recursively get the properties from the `Car` object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this?

Comment: Unless there is a better way to go about this @MatiasCicero ?

Comment: Trying to figure out what you're trying to accomplish. If you know you're looking for `HorsePower`, then you probably already know the structure of the objects.

Comment: I'm trying to do this generically, for any type of object @itsme86

Comment: You can use the property info's `ReflectedType` or `DeclaringType` to determine which type does the property belong to... but I don't think there's a way (using `PropertyInfo`, at least) you can get which "first class" property does a PI belong to. `PropertyInfo`s give information about types, not about class members.

Comment: (what I mean is... say, you had two `Engine` properties on `Car`, you'd have two `Engine` and two `HorsePower` propertyinfos, which would be the same... you would not be able to disambiguate which one of the engines would you be pointing to, nor which one of the engines would the horsepower point to)

Comment: @Puzzled Trying to do *what* generically? Set a specific nested property? How do you know what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jcl You're absolutely right. The answer below would break at that point.

Comment: @Puzzled If you have two properties that return an `Engine` instance, my method would chose the one that is called `Engine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Haven't tested this)*

You can use [MemberInfo.DeclaringType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private static object GetPropertyValue(PropertyInfo property, object instance)
{
    Type root = instance.GetType();
    if (property.DeclaringType == root)
        return property.GetValue(instance);
    object subInstance = root.GetProperty(property.DeclaringType.Name).GetValue(instance);
    return GetPropertyValue(property, subInstance);
}
```

This requires that if `HorsePower` belongs to type `Engine`, you need to have a property called `Engine` in your `Car` type.